# Verify Toast is displayed by Espresso from Android 11

Tags: android-espresso

Does anyone have idea how to verify Toast is displayed by Espresso from Android 11. For Android lower 11, it often be written something like this and it works fine.

```
Espresso.onView(withText("Toast message here"))
.inRoot(withDecorView(not(decorView)))
.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

Thank you all for your idea about that.